# How to generate random numbers with a set number of duplicates > 0

Tags: java, random

Is there a specific way to generate random numbers and only obtaining x amount of duplicates of each number in java with Random?

Comment: Please clarify "x amount of duplicates": does it mean "at most x", "at least x", or "exactly x"?

Comment: By x amount of duplicates I mean exactly x.

Comment: This clarification should be edited into the question; it seems the answerer understood as "at most x". I would try generating random numbers normally, then repeat each  x times and reshuffle at random.

Comment: What is the range of your random numbers? Possibly from -99999999 to 999999999 ? And also, how many times do you need to generate the random number? Possibly more than a million times?

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no way to use the Random API to generate a list of numbers with a user-defined duplicate limit. You're best bet is to generate the numbers (with Random) and then discard duplicates after they appear more than x times. You could use a duplicate supporting multimap implementation to do this, maybe com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll look into the multimap implementation.